# How to add children to ScrollPane

Tags: javafx, nodes, fxml

Now, I've looked around for a while, but I haven't found anything that helps me. I'm trying to create a chat-based game, which utilizes JavaFX-FXML and relies on a ScrollPane.

I'm trying to create JLabels and add them to the ScrollPane dynamically.

With my own research I found that you can't set multiple children for a ScrollPane; you have to use the `setContent` method and have a pane to add the children inside of that, so that's what I did but I still get an error when adding the labels. It's inside the IDE and tells me I have to use a Node but I don't know what a node is.

Here's my controller:

```
public class Controller() {

import javax.swing.*;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.input.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import static jdk.nashorn.internal.objects.NativeError.printStackTrace;

private String msg;
private char[] msgA;
@FXML
private Label opt1;
@FXML
private Label opt2;
@FXML
private Label opt3;
@FXML
private TextField msgBox;
@FXML
private AnchorPane gameUI;
@FXML
private AnchorPane mainMenu;
@FXML public ScrollPane labelPane;
private boolean optionSelected = false;

    private void startup(){
        System.out.println("startup called! Getting player's name now..");
        String mcName=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Please enter your name");
        System.out.println(mcName+" was inputted, let's hope it's an appropriate name! Haha!");

        JLabel label = new JLabel();
        label.setName("evieHi");
        label.setText("Hi "+mcName+"! How are you doing?");
        labelPane.setContent(p);

        opt1.setText("I'm good, how are you?");
        opt2.setText("Not so well until you texted. ;D");
        opt3.setText("I'm sorry, who is this?");

        Pane p = new Pane();
        p.getChildren().add(label);
    }

}
```

I do realize some of the imports and variables are redundant. They're not relevant to my question so I left the methods using them out of my code I included.

Thanks in advance and I'm sorry you had to read my messy code.

Comment: Why are you creating `JLabel`s in a JavaFX application?

Comment: @James_D Probably because I'm stupid and am missing something important..

Comment: `JLabel` is a swing component. Of course you can't add it to a JavaFX pane.

Comment: @James_D That would make sense.... Sorry for my ignorance, and thanks for your help!

Comment: a) imports belong to the start of the file not inside the type declaration. b) just use `javafx.scene.control.Label` instead of `JLabel`s. c) You need to declare/initialize the variable `p` ***before*** you use it. d) `startup` is a private method not annotated with `@FXML` and you're not using it in this class but there is no way of accessing the method from other classes without reflection. What is the purpose of this method?

Comment: @fabian I'm sorry, I kinda copy+pasted everything all "willy nilly" the imports are located at the start of the file. Also, I should've clarified, startup is only called once by the press of a "Play" button on the main menu. I just needed syntax help for `startup()` but also needed to know what i did wrong for use in a `createLabel()` method

Answer (score 0):

Attempting to create a Swing UI component doesn't bode well with JavaFX...
I fixed it with the help of @James_D and @fabian pointing out what I'm to dumb to realize..

```
private void startup(){
    System.out.println("startup called! Getting player's name now..");
    mcName=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Please enter your name");
    System.out.println(mcName+" was inputted,let's hope it's an appropriate name! Haha!");
    Label label = new Label();
    label.setText("Hi "+mcName+"! How are you doing?");
    p.getChildren().add(label);
    labelPane.setContent(p);
}
```